# Angular2 bind components to API endpoint

Tags: angular, bind

I'm building an Angular2 application and I'm also building pages using nested components.

However, I do have one use case where one nested component, which acts as a filter, should make all the other nested components update the information displayed based on whatever was set on that filter.
I'm attaching a scheme of what my page looks like and what I'd like to achieve.

[image]

I already know that a nested component can emit events on whatever the parent component is to trigger whatever defined action.

However, I'd like to know two things:
- Can I bind a component to a given API endpoint, and have that component update the information displayed (by making a request to the endpoint) dependent on whatever is set on the filter?
- How can I make all my components on a page depend on the filter if they are not directly bound to an API endpoint?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an Injectable() service that you can reach from all your components.

You declare a service by annotating a class with @Injectable(). Then add this class to the providers array of your app module - which will make it globally available to all components - acting as a singleton service. Finally inject the service into your components using the constructor of the component class, and you now have a central object where your filter results components can read the state of the filter settings.

Read more about services here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Comment: Hello Peter. Thank you for the info. I already have a service that does that but what you are basically telling me is that either I have a function per component in the service (and I need to inject the service in each component) or that I have a service in the top-level parent component and initialise the children from the parent, but no direct binding to API endpoint right? It's a little bit of a disappointment, I must admit, but it still seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: I think you should access the API endpoint from the service and send requests from the service to the API endpoint whenever the filter state is changed. And then have your results components get their data from the Injectable service. Wouldn't that give you the binding that you want to achieve?